# Pandas conditionally set column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following excel

```
 A         B    
'Text1'   NaN
'Text2'   'Text7'
'Text3'   'Text8'
'Text4'   NaN
'Text5'   NaN
```

I would like to set a third column conditionally

Set C column as A + '_' + B only if B is not empty. If B is empty set C to A

```
 A         B        C
'Text1'   NaN      'Text1'
'Text2'   'Text7'  'Text2_Text7' 
'Text3'   'Text8'  'Text3_Text8'
'Text4'   NaN      'Text4'
'Text5'   NaN      'Text5'
```

Is it possible to do using pandas?

I have the following code so far

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx')
```

Update:

I have updated the values to be string. I think the solutions given works for int data type but not string.

Comment: Are those missing values `NaN` or actual whitespaces when you use `print(df)`

Comment: try 2 separate commands for empty and non-enpty df.b:
`df.loc[~df.b.isna(),'c'] = df.a + df.b`
`df.loc[df.b.isna(),'c'] = df.a `

Comment: @RuslanS.your solution worked!. Please post it as answer, so that I can mark it.

Answer (score 0):

**Are you looking for something like this ?**

```
df.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
df['C'] = df.A + df.B
import numpy as np
df.replace(0, np.nan, inplace=True)


   A    B    C
0  1  NaN  1.0
1  2  4.0  6.0
2  3  5.0  8.0
3  4  NaN  4.0
4  5  NaN  5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 'B': [np.nan, 4,5, np.nan,np.nan]})
df['C'] = df['A'].add(df['B']).fillna(df['A']) 
   A    B    C
0  1  NaN  1.0
1  2  4.0  6.0
2  3  5.0  8.0
3  4  NaN  4.0
4  5  NaN  5.0
```